# Why is the image converter not showing in namespace?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-namespaces, ivalueconverter

I am trying to load a few hundred images in a listview without locking the image file. I want to be able to delete the file while the program is running. I created a custom image converter and bind it to the listview.

However, the code is not compiling and I am getting 'The name "ImageConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:CoolApp.ImageConverter'

What am I doing wrong?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CoolApp.MainWindow"
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CoolApp"
                        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:CoolApp.ImageConverter"
                        mc:Ignorable="d"
                        Title="MainWindow" MinHeight="600" Height="600" MinWidth="800" Width="800" 
                       Background="#FF222431" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
                    <Window.Resources>
                        <c:ImageConverter x:Key="ImgConverter" />
                    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid Name="ThumbGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,0,0" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ListView x:Name="Thumbview" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="1" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="{Binding title}" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Image Name="Thumbnails" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding picPath, Converter={StaticResource ImgConverter}, IsAsync=True}" Stretch="Uniform" Height="255" Width="170" ToolTip="{Binding title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        </Image>
                                    </Grid>               
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        </ListView>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

C#:

```
namespace CoolApp
{


    public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

                var image = new BitmapImage();
                image.BeginInit();
                image.UriSource = value is Uri ? (Uri)value : new Uri(value.ToString());
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.EndInit();
                return image;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

//code to add images to ItemsSource
}
```

Comment: Try with namespace `xmlns:c="clr-namespace:CoolApp"` instead ? in your case `<c:ImageConverter x:Key="ImgConverter" />` is interpreted to `<c:CoolApp.ImageConverter.ImageConverter x:Key="ImgConverter" />`

Comment: Just a note, to save some memory, you could also call `image.Freeze()` after `image.EndInit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ImageConverter` is defined inside `CoolApp` namespace while you are telling the compiler to look for `ImageConverter` inside `CoolApp.ImageConverter` namespace, because of a wrong namespace mapping in your xaml. 
Your namespace mapping should be like this:

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:CoolApp"
```